# Stuck updating one field based on the condition of another using Acrpy or Field Calculator

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table, cursor

I have a shapefile with 5,000 city points. I need to populate a new field, "cls_pop", based on each cities population, so that cities with a population > 2,000,000 will have "cls_pop" = 1, cites with a population > 1,800,000 and < 1,600,000 = 2 and so on and so on. I know there are a lot of different ways to accomplish this and I think I have really confused myself reading to much. I want to write this as a arcpy script so I can change out the variables and use it on different fields but I'm unsure of the best way to go about this. I wrote this but it just places "1" in each row of pop_class.

```
city_points = "C:\\Desktop\\citypoints.shp"

cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(city_points,"", "", "population")

for row in cursor:
    if row.getValue(cursor) > 2000000:
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(city_points, "cls_pop", '"{0}"'.format(1), "PYTHON")

    if row.getValue(cursor) > 1800000 and row.getValue(field) < 2000000:
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(city_points, "cls_pop", '"{0}"'.format(2), "PYTHON")

    ect……………….
```

Am I on the correct track or is there a better way for me to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't `row.getValue(cursor)` be `row.getValue("pop_class")`

Comment: No because I need to get the value from the cursor in order to populate cls_pop. So if cursor is > greater than 2000000 I want cls_pop to = 1

Comment: cursor is a Cursor object which gives you a row which contains the data.  I'm pretty sure you need to do `row.population`. `getValue(field_name)` takes a field name `cursor` is not a field ref http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001q000000

Comment: If the classes have uniform widths, then perhaps the easiest and fastest solution is to compute `cls_pop` arithmetically. This can be done in one simple field calculation. Although the description in the question seems confused (it skips from the interval [2000000, Infinity] to [1600000, 1800000]) it likely is intended to equal `max(1, 11 - int("population"/200000))`, which assigns 1 to [2000000, infinity), 2 to [1800000, 2000000), 3 to [1600000, 1800000), and so on, down to 11 for [0, 200000).

Answer (score 3):

This code is untested but I think will be much closer to what you want - key first thing is that you need to use an UpdateCursor.

The other thing that I have done is to use three ways to get and set the values of the current row in your cursor - in practice just choose one of them.

The first (on the `if`) is the simplest but "hardwires" the field names.
The second (on the `elif`) uses a slightly longer syntax but still "hardwires" the field names.
The last (on the `else`) lets you pass in a variable holding the field name.

```
city_points = "C:\\Desktop\\citypoints.shp"

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(city_points)
classPopVar = "cls_pop"

for row in cursor:
    if row.population >= 2000000:
        row.cls_pop = 1
    elif row.getValue("population") >= 1800000 and row.getValue("population") < 2000000:
        row.setValue("cls_pop") = 2
    else:
        row.setValue(classPopVar) = 3
del row,cursor
```

Comment: Easy as that. On a side note: how does arcpy handle a column like `cls pop` when using the `row.` style?

Comment: Pretty sure that it would not like it. Personally I never try blanks in field names because [**this page**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n000000zw000000) says "Database management systems have different definitions of acceptable characters for object names. Most must begin with a letter and cannot contain spaces or back slashes."

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll be testing this out first thing in the morning when I get back to the office and let you know how it works.

Comment: I just got to my office and ran the code but there is a syntax error "There's an error in your program: *** can't assign to function call (line 15)"
Line 15 in my code row.setValue("cls_pop") = 2

Comment: I think this means that "C:\\Desktop\\citypoints.shp" does not have a numeric field called "cls_pop" so can you check the field name and type are as expected, please?